# Transition between two viewControllers presented by rootView controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uianimation

My use case as follows:

- VC1 - Root Controller
- VC2 & VC3 are different view controllers
- VC1 is delegate of VC2
- VC1 presents VC2
- Then as delegated, VC1 dismiss VC2
- Right after dismiss VC2, VC1 presents VC3

In the last step my transition goes bad as after dismissVC2 and beforePresentVC3, VC1 is visible during transition

How can I fix this problem or is it even possible??

NOTE: I want VC1 in window herirarchy so that I can go to VC1 from VC3

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
//while dismising VC2 ,present VC3 here with animated NO
}];

Comment: NO i am saying while dismising VC2

Comment: I tried that..did not work which means VC1 is visible while VC3 is being presented.

Comment: you are using animate :yes while presenting VC3  ?

Comment: @adnan yes..I am usign :yes

Comment: Why must VC1 present VC3?  How about have VC2 do it?  You can still inform VC1 via a delegate method, and you can still dismiss back to VC1 by having VC1 do [self dismiss ...

Comment: @danh I want VC3 -> VC1. if VC2 presents it then VC3 -> VC2 -> VC1. For me VC2 is transient VC and not really part of app navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting into some trouble with no sense. You could easily have a hidden navigationController and create and stack every VC and then move around with

```
self.navigationController popToViewController: animated:
```

or

```
self.navigationController pushToViewController: animated:
```

then you could move from 1 to 3, or 3 to 1 with no problem. If you created all the VCs and are available to access from any of the 3 vcs